# Sending USB and audio to LCD through thunderbolt

Tags: display, audio, usb, hardware

It is disappointing to me that in order to use my monitor's USB ports, I have to send 2 Data cables from my MacBook to my monitor: Thunderbolt->DVI and USB->USB.

In order to use my monitor's inbuilt speakers, I require at least one more cable (speaker power), which requires an awkward transformer.

It seems like bad design, the monitor should power its own speakers, and USB should automatically extends through the data cable.

It is sometime since I bought my kit. Is it now possible to do this? Do modern MacBook video outputs at modern monitors support this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no Thunderbolt to DVI adapter. You're using a Mini DisplayPort to DVI adapter. Mini DisplayPort doesn't support anything other than DisplayPort data. USB cannot travel over this. If the monitor requires an external power supply, presumably Mini DisplayPort doesn't have enough power either. If this was a Thunderbolt monitor, it would likely still need a power cord, but it wouldn't need the USB cables, because Thunderbolt basically supports everything.